# RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_SDK is incorrect

Tags: android, ruby, sdk, android-ndk, rubymotion

I have developed android apps in java so I have android-sdk and android-ndk in `~/AndroidStudioProjects/adt-bundle/sdk`. I have all the APIs downloaded in there, almost 6-8gb file.

But, when I typed `motion android-setup` to setup android environment for RubyMotion, it downloaded sdk+ndk on its own in `~/.rubymotion-android/`. However, the process could not complete

```
❯ motion android-setup                                         
Installed SDK is up-to-date.
Installed NDK is up-to-date.
[error] RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_SDK is incorrect, should be /Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/sdk
add `export RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_SDK=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/sdk` to your ~/.profile
[error] RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_NDK is incorrect, should be /Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/ndk
add `export RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/ndk` to your ~/.profile
```

So I guess the two android sdk locations are clashing with each other.

I also outputted

```
export RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_SDK=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/sdk
export RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_SDK=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/sdk
```

in RubyMotion `.zshrc, .bash_profile, .profile` in `~` dir. But, I still get those ruby motion sdk and ndk are incorrect. I am using zsh shell instead of bash so I thought I should keep the export lines in zshrc instead of bashrc. By it didn't worked. So, I kept export lines in all files. But could get it to work.

How can I get it fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with not updating RubyMotion to latest build.

Update via `sudo motion update`

Then update xcode to the latest build from App Store and everything should worok fine.